# How to integreate Angular with springMVC 4.3.1

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I have old application with **AngularJs** and Spring MVC 4.3.1,

Is there any way to integrate **Angular** with Spring MVC 4.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can replace an AngularJs app that uses a Spring app as a back-end with an Angular app that uses the same back end, then the answer is 'yes' - just rewrite the AngularJs app with Angular and use the same api.

If that's not what you mean, please explain.